# cannot install the utorrent application on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: utorrent

by seeing the previous threads i tried the steps but getting this error.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
bash: /usr/bin/utserver: No such file or directory
```

this is the error. tried at least 10 times but cannot resolve the error. please help.

output of:  ls -la /usr/bin/utserver

shiril@Shiril-PC:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/utserver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Aug  2 16:57 /usr/bin/utserver -> /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver

---

I tried the above steps and got the following result...

```
shiril@Shiril-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo rm -r /opt/utorrent-server-v3*
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/utorrent-server-v3*’: No such file or directory

shiril@Shiril-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo tar xf utserver.tar.gz -C /opt

shiril@Shiril-PC:~/Downloads$ ls -la /opt
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 Aug  4 03:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root   4096 Aug  3 04:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 30 root   root   4096 Aug  1 11:17 lampp
drwxrwxr-x  3 shiril shiril 4096 Jan 15  2014 utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3

shiril@Shiril-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver

shiril@Shiril-PC:~/Downloads$ % utserver -usage
bash: fg: %: no such job

shiril@Shiril-PC:~/Downloads$ % utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3
bash: fg: %: no such job
```

Comment: Why do you want utorrent, when the system has installed Transmission BitTorrent Client.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/utserver`

Comment: Edited my answer, don't use the leading `℅` in point 5, it's my shell prompt. Simply repeat the steps in point 5.

Answer (score 0):

The version number has changed. There is not longer a version 3.0. The current version is 3.3. Therefore I assume, you don't have a folder `/opt/utorrent-server-v3_0`

1. Housekeeping

   ```
   sudo rm -r /opt/utorrent-server-v3*
   ```
2. Extract the archive again

   ```
   sudo tar xf utserver.tar.gz -C /opt
   ```
3. Check the created folder in `/opt`

   ```
   ls -la /opt
   ```

   E.G.

   ```
   drwxrwxr-x  4 4096 Aug  2 21:33 utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3
   ```
4. Create the symbolic link and use the correct folder name, see point 3.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
   ```
5. That's all

   `utserver -usage`

   ```
   Locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
   330B (30470) 2014-01-14 09:10:15 -0800
   Usage:  utserver -settingspath -logfile -configfile -pidfile -daemon -usage
       settingspath - location of settings directory
       logfile - location and name of log file
       configfile - location and name of configuration file
       pidfile - location and name of file to contain process ID
       daemon - run process as a daemon
       usage - print this message and exit
   ```

   Start the server (and use the correct folder name, see point 3)

   `utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3`

   [image]

Comment: @shiril: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**